# String evaluation of PHP int(0)

Tags: php, string

Why would this expression evaluate to true in PHP:

```
0 == " UNKNOWN"
```

Comment: So you're saying `0 == " UNKNOWN"` is also true?

Comment: Are you saying you are comparing an `int` with a `string`?

Comment: A lot of strings evaluate to `0` in PHP; the moral is to never use `==`. (Or PHP, for that matter – if you can help it.)

Comment: Ah, to answer my own question, yes.

To 'fix' your code, use === instead of ==.

Comment: If you really want to test things, use `===` because it compares not only content, but the type as well. E.g.: `0=="0" - True`, `0==="0" - False`

Comment: Yeah, as lemondrop said... when it compares 0 to "some string", it checks the values, so it converts them to the same type for the value comparison. `0 == "0"` but `0 != "1"`;

Comment: `intval("UNKNOWN")` is `0`, I guess thats why.

Comment: @minitech "Or PHP, for that matter – if you can help it" - How dare you! There are like whole WEBPAGES built with PHP :P

Comment: I upvoted this question by the way, I don't know why others have downvoted it. The person asked a valid question. Is there a way to downvote bad downvoters?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be found in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the string is coerced to an int for comparison, and the int value of that string is 0.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a loose comparison between two variables; the rules for using that operator are covered in the [loose comparison table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).

Answer (score 2):

`==` will typecast one of your values to match the other.

`(int)" UNKNOWN"` returns 0

`(int)0` returns 0

so

`0==" UNKNOWN"` is `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string == " UNKNOWN";
var_dump((int)$string); //gives 0
```

so it evaluates to true.